# Windows batch file ren using date variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, file-rename

Learned batch a while ago in school, haven't ever used it until now b/c I had an idea.  Just for fun I wanted to mess around with powercfg batteryreport with my new laptop, but I want to archive.  I was going to try and figure out how to have the file powercfg batteryreport spits out changed in some sort of numerical order but I don't even know where to begin, so I decided to just make a new line that takes the current file created and adds the date.  All of this is taking place inside of a special folder I created, so pathing isnt necessary.

```
    @echo off
    powercfg batteryreport
    rename "battery-report.html" "batteryreport %date%.html"
```

This exact script works without the date variable, but never with it in, but of course I need a variable present in order to have multiple reports saved, as opposed to it writing over itself every time.  I've tried messing with all spacings, quotes vs no quotes, no luck.  Help (or a better way, preferably with explanation) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood, your `date` format contains `/` which is illegal in a filename.

Use `%date:/=-%` in place of `%date%`. this converts each `/` to `-` (see `set /?` from the prompt for docco)

Equally, you could use `%time::=.%` o convert the time to a version usable in a filename.

---

To remove dayname, you need to use an intermediate variable:

```
set "dateonly=%date:* =%"
ren ... "...%dateonly:/=-%..."
```

The `*` means "all of the characters up to and including the first space" and this is replaced by *nothing* (the string following the `=`)

see `set /?` from the prompt for details.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I hadn't thought of that!  The time variable helped a lot too, now I can make as many files as I want.  Thanks so much!

Comment: How might I go about removing the "Thu" from the date so it only gives me dd/mm/yyyy?